# SocketException (0x2afc): The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found

Tags: model-view-controller, socketexception

I've just upgraded one of my clients from a very old version of our software to the latest version.  While the Windows application side of the software is working, the new MVC application is getting the error above.  Both the Windows and Web application uses .NET Remoting to connect to the server components.

I've searched the web for this error but all I can find are DNS related issues (which is also reflected in the stack traces posted) so mine doesn't seem to be related to DNS issues.  Also, the web application in this case is on the same server as the server components that the app is connecting to plus my Windows and Web application uses exactly the same config file.  Windows application works from both the server self and over VPN connection.

Here is my stack trace:

```
Server Error in '/MyApp' Application.

The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 

[SocketException (0x2afc): The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found]
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +14799926
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +622
MyApp.Common.ServerInterfaces.IGeneral.GetStartupData(String CurrentVersion, Boolean CompressResults, ProgramModuleEnum Caller) +0
MyApp.Web.Infrastructure.BaseController.GetAppData(Boolean ForceRefresh) +388
ASP._Page_Views_Security_Login_vbhtml.Execute() +228
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +280
System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +126
System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +143
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +110
System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +380
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +109
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +97
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +241
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +19
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +51
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

This is an established application and the first time I've gotten this error (only with this specific client).  The server was still on .NET 4.0 so I upgraded to .NET 4.5.1 (which the latest version of my app requires) and restarted the server which caused my Windows app to work but the web still doesn't.

Comment: Anybody?  Found a similar issue at http://serverfault.com/questions/525592/net-socketexception-the-requested-name-is-valid-but-no-data-of-the-requested/738826#738826, but wasn't answered either.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, no idea what happened.  After the weekend, I tried the web application again and it just worked.  No server restarts or updates to the server at all.  (Although, I did restart the server last week after installing .NET 4.5.1, but that didn't resolve the issue either).

Sorry, but it seems this might not help anyone else with a similar error.